# iOS - Why is there an error?

Tags: ios, xcode

Here is my Code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"startGame"]) {
        UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.grade = self.currentGrade;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
(!)Semantic Issue:
    Property "grade" not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'
```

Why do I get this error? I defined it as a property of the view controller and hooked it up in the storyboard.

Comment: Maybe segue.destinationViewController; is returning null or whatever returns objetive-c?

Comment: You have to declare grade variable in your nextView controller

Comment: Cast to the specific name of your UIViewController instead of casting it to UIViewController directly.

Comment: because the `UIViewController` has no such property as `grade`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type cast to your viewController

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"startGame"]) {
            YourViewController *controller = (YourViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            controller.grade = self.currentGrade;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if the answer is relevant to u,plz make the tickmark

Answer (score 1):

Possbile Case : Check Your `UIViewController` Custom Class. As the `segue.destinationViewController;` will return you the object of `ViewController` what you bind with your root view.

As In Your Case :

```
UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.grade = self.currentGrade;
```

Your Access the `grade` property of your `UIViewController` and its not finding so it may be one of the reason of this crash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The grade is your custom property.
You can customize a viewcontroller, and it define a property: grade.